# Unable to add spatie/laravel-sluggable package in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I tried to add **spatie/laravel-sluggable** in my setup but faced this error in the terminal. I tried to search this but didn't find any relevant solution.

Here is the error:

```
Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - spatie/laravel-sluggable 2.1.0 requires illuminate/database ~5.5.0 
      -> satisfiable by illuminate/database[v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44].
    - spatie/laravel-sluggable 2.1.5 requires illuminate/database ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~5.7.0 
      -> satisfiable by illuminate/database[5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
    - spatie/laravel-sluggable 2.1.6 requires illuminate/database ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~5.7.0 
      -> satisfiable by illuminate/database[5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12,
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.34|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.35|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.37|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.39|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.40|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.41|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.43|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.5.44|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.4.36, required as 5.4.*) 
      -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.36].
    - Installation request for spatie/laravel-sluggable ^2.1 
      -> satisfiable by spatie/laravel-sluggable[2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.6].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I also tried to add `illuminate/database` but it also showed the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always verify the requirements of a package in its **composer.json** file.

For example, in your case, you can check the **composer.json** here:
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable/blob/master/composer.json#L18#L23

You can notice this:

```
"require": {
    "php" : ">=7.0.0",
    "illuminate/database": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~5.7.0",
    "illuminate/support": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~5.7.0"
},
```

Here it says the minimum PHP version required and also mentions the `illuminate/database` and `illuminate/support` package version requirement, which is **5.5**, **5.6** and **5.7** and above.

These illuminate packages are for Laravel. They are the core packages of the Laravel framework so their version should match with your laravel version.

You cannot install the old illuminate package on newer Laravel version.

I would suggest you upgrade your **Laravel to 5.5** or to the latest one. Spatie and their packages are most of the times up to date so you better update yours as well.

Answer (score 2):

This package `spatie/laravel-sluggable` requires:

```
php: >=7.0.0
illuminate/database: ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~5.7.0
illuminate/support: ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~5.7.0
```

You can't install this package in your **laravel 5.4** framework

If you want to use this([spatie/laravel-sluggable](https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/laravel-sluggable)) then you need **laravel 5.5** or higher version.

If you have Laravel 5.5 or higher then you can run this command at your command prompt:

```
composer require spatie/laravel-sluggable
```

This will generate the latest version for your project

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to upgrade to Laravel 5.5 you can install version [1.5.2](https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/laravel-sluggable#1.5.2) of `spatie/laravel-sluggable` which is Laravel 5.4 compatible.

```
composer require spatie/laravel-sluggable "^1.5"
```

Comment: I decided to update the laravel as @pankaj said its better to update else this problem may reoccur in future. Thanks anyway.